# Is there a better way to write this random list function?

Tags: python, list, random

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    rand = random.randint(0,place)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

^This is my error. I'm not sure why this code isn't working as I'm new to Python. I'm trying to write a code that detects how big a list is, then selects a random item from the list.

```
import random

greetings = ["hello","hola","bonjour","privet","ciao","guten tag","shalom"]

place = 0
for i in greetings:
  place = i

rand = random.randint(0,place)
print(greetings[rand])
```

^This is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The loop makes no sense; I'm guessing you intended to find the final index, but the correct way of doing that is just `place = len(greetings) - 1` (or use `place = len(greetings)` and use `random.randrange(place)` saving the `- 1`). But yes, as the answers point out, `random.choice` is the correct way to do this, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: In Python the `len` function is used to find the length of a list i.e. `len(greetings)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet:

```
place = 0
for i in greetings:
  place = i
```

Boils down to just being a really complicated way of getting the last list element of `grettings`, which probably isn't what you expected nor wanted. The name `i` might suggest that you thought these were index integers, but in fact, the value of `i` is just each greeting in the list. Each one is written to `place` in order, and only the last value sticks. I.e. for your particular `greetings` array, the value of `place` will always end up as `"shalom"`.

This returns the following line into `rand = random.randint(0, "shalom")`, which clearly makes no sense.

A *correct* (but bad) example might actually iterate over the indices:

```
last_list_index = 0 # Renamed from "place" for clarity 
for i in range(len(greetings)):
  last_list_index = i

list_length = last_list_index + 1
random_index = random.randint(0, list_length)
print(greetings[random_index])
```

But of course, that's convoluted too. Why waste time iterating over all the indices to just get the last one? You can just call `len(greetings)` to get the list length directly:

```
random_index = random.randint(0, len(greetings))
print(greetings[random_index])
```

But wait, there's more! There's a more specific tool for the job that is made for exactly this:

```
import random

greetings = ["hello","hola","bonjour","privet","ciao","guten tag","shalom"]

random_greeting = random.choice(greetings)
print(random_greeting)
```

Comment: In the correct (but bad) for loop, I think you meant: `for i in range(len(greetings)):`

Comment: @DarrylG I did! You can feel free to make corrections like that directly to the answer :)

Comment: thanks, a great suggestion, but if the person has a lot higher reputation I would fear doing that rather than asking as a comment :)

Comment: @DarrylG Worry not, if a person has much higher reputation, they're _more_ likely to understand the benefit of third party edits, and are probably more welcoming to it. Just make sure your edit is correct, in the spirit of the author's original intent (e.g. don't change a direction they propose with another, for large differences like that just make a new answer) and if necessary, explain your edit in the summary line

Answer (score 6):

Don't reinvent the wheel. The `random` module has [`choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.choice) function exactly for this purpose:

```py
print(random.choice(greetings))
```